# Is between in R

Tags: r

I would like to check the elements of vector `a` is between the elements of vector `b` or not in R. How can I do this ? Means that is 3 between 2 and 4 and if yes appear in result, if not do not appear. Just mentiond that I dont want to check the first and last element of vector a. The result should be just 3.

```
      a = c(1, 3, 8, 12)
      b = c(0, 2, 4, 6, 8)
```

Comment: I find the question somewhat ambiguous. What do you expect the output to be in your example, and why?

Comment: here is ugly and poorly tested code that might be right: res <- findInterval(a[-c(1, length(a))], b); a[res[!b[res] %in% b[c(1, length(b))]]]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

why don't you just use a loop?

```
> a = c(1, 3, 8, 12)
> b = c(0, 2, 4, 6, 8)
> for (i in 2:(length(a)-1)){ if (b[i] < a[i] && a[i] <b[i+1]) {print (a[i])}}
[1] 3
```

Comment: I wonder why the answer is down-voted. It is accepted as correct answer. Is my answer too straightforward (such that nobody bothers to type it)? Could the voters please justify themselves? Or provide suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

Here's how I would do it:

```
> Interval <- cut(a, b, FALSE)            ## Which 'slot' of b does a fit into?
> Interval
[1]  1  2  4 NA
> Interval == 1:length(a)                 ## Does it fit sequentially?
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE   NA
```

Since `a[4]` falls outside of `b` entirely, you can either replace all `NA` values with `FALSE` afterwards (i.e. `Vec[is.na(Vec)] <- F`) or use `c(b,max(a))` instead of `b` in the cut function.